# Best way to apply a class to one element when another is selected (via Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a long form laid out in Bootstrap, with the labels in one column and the inputs in another to the right. To help clarify to the user which field he's editing, I would like to change the color of the label when focusing on the corresponding input, then change the color back to default on blur. I could do this easily in jQuery, but since there's a lot of overlap between jQuery and Angular, I'd rather not include both. That said, I'm pretty new to Angular, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm trying to change the class on the label, not the input itself, so a pure CSS solution does not apply here.

Comment: You could use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` directives for that.

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to change the CSS class of a label contained in another div, not the input being focused on.

Comment: Angular is not a DOM manipulation library as they state explicitly in the docs. If you need DOM manipulation (which it sounds like you do) you should bite the bullet and include jQuery. Or you can try your hand at some vanilla javascript (preferred since you only implement what you need instead of lighting a cigarette with a cruise missle)

Comment: "Angular is not a DOM manipulation library as they state explicitly in the docs."
Can you show me where it says that in the docs? I'm not sure what the point of two way data binding and directives like ng-class would be if not for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke – it is, but it isn't jQuery. Look under the first Common Pitfall http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq You are looking for the `ng-class` directive

Comment: Understood, but it offers ng-focus, ng-blur, and ng-class directives, all of which seem like they'd be applicable to this particular problem. I'm just not sure how best to structure the solution.

Comment: I'm a strong believer in fishing polls over fish on SO, so the best advice I can give you without giving you the answer is to bone up on your knowledge of how `$scope` and expressions work – http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression ––– By "giving you the answer" I mean writing the code for you

Comment: Based on that link, I'm not sure you understand the question. Here's a solution I came up with, as an example:

`<label for="testField" ng-class="{highlight: $scope.highlight}">Test:</label>
<input id="testField" ng-model="testField" ng-focus="$scope.highlight = true" ng-blur="$scope.highlight = false"/>`

So when you click on the input, the highlight class gets applied to the label, and when you click off, the class gets removed. The problem is that the form has ~40 fields, and I'm trying to avoid creating a model for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set css for focus. it's that simple. no jQuery, no AngularJS

```
input:focus
{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/czAmSlOvd1ZYJLoVK5h7?p=preview

------------ edit ------------------
Since poster asked to highlight a label, not input. I provide another answer using angularJS directive

HTML looks like this

```
  <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
  <input id="firstname" hilight-label />
```

And here is the directive. It listens to the event `focus` and `blur` and set/unset highlight class

```
  var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.directive('hilightLabel', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, el, attr) {
        var hilightClass = (attr.hightLabel || 'hilight');
        var label = document.querySelector("label[for="+el[0].id+"]");
        el[0].addEventListener('focus', function(){
          label.className += (" " + hilightClass);
        });
        el[0].addEventListener('blur', function(){
          var regEx = new RegExp('\\b' + hilightClass+ '\\b');
          label.className = label.className.replace(regEx,'');
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/czAmSlOvd1ZYJLoVK5h7?p=preview

Comment: That only works if I'm trying to change the CSS on the input field itself or a label wrapped inside the input field, neither of which applies in this case.

Comment: Provided another solution with edit using AngularJS directive

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best solution I've come up with so far:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="name" ng-class="{highlight: $scope.highlightName}">Name:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="name" ng-focus="$scope.highlightName = true" ng-blur="$scope.highlightName = false" />
</div>
```

It works, but I feel like there should be a more concise way to go about this, so if anyone has a better solution, please post it!